# how to make this javascript code shorter?

Tags: javascript, html

I created this small game while ago and now i'm trying it find a way to make it script short and simpler i was wondering if there is any another way . I have four pics of animals and blow the pic i have four names . what the game suppose to do is when the users click on right image and right name both the image and the name has to disappear. Any help really appreciate it

```html
function image_select() {
    var pic1 = document.getElementById("cow").value;
    var text1 = document.getElementById("cow_t").value;

    if (document.getElementById("cow").checked) {
        if (pic1 == text1) {
            var x = document.getElementById("cow_s");
            x.play();
        } else {
            alert("wrong selection");
        }
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }
}

function image_select2() {
    var pic2 = document.getElementById("dog").value;
    var text2 = document.getElementById("dog_t").value;

    if (document.getElementById("dog").checked) {
        if (pic2 == text2) {
            var x = document.getElementById("dog_s");
            x.play();
        } else {
            alert("wrong selection");
        }
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }

}


function image_select3() {
    var pic3 = document.getElementById("horse").value;
    var text3 = document.getElementById("horse_t").value;

    if (document.getElementById("horse").checked) {
        if (pic3 == text3) {
            var x = document.getElementById("horse_s");
            x.play();
        } else {
            alert("wrong selection");
        }
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }

}

function image_select4() {
    var pic4 = document.getElementById("pig").value;
    var text4 = document.getElementById("pig_t").value;

    if (document.getElementById("pig").checked) {
        if (pic4 == text4) {
            var x = document.getElementById("pig_s");
            x.play();
        } else {
            alert("wrong selection");
        }
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }

}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left:230px;">
    <br>
    <br>
<img onmousedown="dog.play()" height="142" width="142" src="image/cow.jpg" alt="Cow" data-value="cow" onclick="selectImage(event)" />
 <img  height="142" width="142" src="image/dog.jpg" alt=""  data-value="dog" onclick="selectImage(event)"/> 
  <img height="142" width="142" src="image/horse.jpg" alt="" data-value="horse" onclick="selectImage(event)"/>  
    <img height="142" width="142"  src="image/pig.jpg" data-value="pig" onclick="selectImage(event)"/>
</div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div style="margin-left:400px;">
     <button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="pig" id="pig_t">Cochon</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="cow" id="cow_t">Vache</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="horse" id="horse_t">Cheval</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="selectName(event)" value="dog" id="dog_t">chien</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: this should probably be on codereview

Answer (score 1):

Just put the name of the animal to the function (in fact, you seem to already does so, since you pass the event to selectName, but I don't see this function in your code) :

```
function image_select_animal(prefix) {
  var pic = document.getElementById(prefix).value;
  var text = document.getElementById(prefix + "_t").value;

  if (document.getElementById(prefix).checked) {
    if (pic == text) {
      var x = document.getElementById(prefix + "_s");
      x.play();
    } else {
      alert("wrong selection");
    }
  } else {
    alert("no");
  }
}
```

and in onclick, call `image_select_animal("pig")` or equivalent for the other animals.

Comment: hi @Samuel Caillerie  Thank you for taking your time and to answer my question. i tried what you wrote but unfortunately does not work :( .

Comment: i really like your solution but unfortunately does not work

Comment: I have just refactor your JS script, but it seems that your snippet is missing some part : image_select and others are never called...

Answer (score 0):

```
function image_select(name) {
    var el = document.getElementById(name); // create this variable, as you use this element twice. Less DOM lookups.
    var pic = el.value; // get the value of the `el` variable
    var text = document.getElementById(name + '_t').value;

    if (!el.checked) { // if not check
        alert('no');
        return; // return ends the function immediately, meaning the following lines are not read
    }

    if (pic != text) {
        alert('wrong selection');
        return; // return ends the function immediately, meaning the following lines are not read
    }

    document.getElementById(name + '_s').play(); // no need to store this in variable x, as you only use this element once.
}
```

Comment: can you explain me a bit more plz

Comment: @afgboy - I believe to have fixed it. Also, I added more comments. Does this help?

Comment: for the function image_select(name) do i need to change (name) with something or should i leave it like this ?

Comment: No, you keep it as is: `name` is an argument. It means that when you call `image_select()` you provide a value inside the `()`. E.g. you would call `image_select('cow')` or `image_select('pig')`. 

That way you have only one function, and keep re-using it.

In general, if you are writing the same code across different functions, you should put the repeating code into its separate function.

Comment: do i need to do create 3 more functions or this one function is going to work for all the images ?i"m really lost bro haha

Comment: I don't believe there are errors in my code, but you might be calling `image_select` correctly. 

Could I ask you to create an example with https://jsfiddle.net/ and share it?

Comment: Could I ask you to share a working example of jsfiddle.net ? Then we can work together to make it shorter.

Comment: If you open your browser's web inspector / console, you will see errors. You are also including `<html>` and `<head>` tags in your jsfiddle which are not needed. Lastly you are loading in `test.js` which is not referenced anywhere.

Comment: it was my first time using jsfiddle. thank you for correcting me

Comment: people like you make this world beautiful

Comment: @afgboy - Please see my JSFiddle for an example approach https://jsfiddle.net/1fz3dhcq/

Comment: Can you add a correct version of my code to your solution so i can give a vote up plz

Comment: @afgboy - I'm going to have to ask you to do this last part on your own. You're almost there. Make small changes, and keep checking if it works. Big problems are the sum of many small problems.

Comment: bro youre code has error even if i select the right image and right name it says wrong .i select pig pic and name .it said its wrong

Comment: Whoops! I forgot to change the `value` of the top `input` to `chicken` and `pig`. I have created a new version with the correction. Check it out and read the comments, hope this helps! https://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/4unuf3gw/

Comment: i really did not understand one thing .i copy exavtly ur code and run it but i do not know why it does not work for me and it does not show any errors